# Simple Jquery POST call not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I got a simple POST call to a PHP file on my website. For some reason it's not working though. The console.log shows"undefined"

```
function check() {
  var url = "../API/keychecker.php";
  var spullen = $("keyval").val;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {
      key: spullen
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  })
}
```

Here is the PHP file:

```
<?php
  echo json_encode($_POST['key']);
?>
```

Comment: What does your browser console show for the PHP file under the network tab?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/wd4oh3u

Comment: Try with absolute path to keychecker.php + try keychecker.php manually to see if there are any errors.

Comment: @NathanReul look under `Response` && `Preview`

Comment: this `$( "keyval" ).val;` typo, missing `.` or `#`

Comment: Also give us a direct link, that will speed up things. Also as @Ghost said + val is a function therefore should be val()

Answer (score 3):

Your `keyval` call doesn't specify the type of element identifier. jQuery won't find the element you're looking for as you currently have it.

You must specify:

For classes:

```
$( ".keyval" ).val();
```

For ID

```
$( "#keyval" ).val();
```

For input name

```
$( "input[name=keyval]" ).val();
```

That should attach the value to the `POST` request.

Comment: You would also want val() for jquery.  val is a function.

Answer (score 0):

var url = "API/keychecker.php";
var spullen = $( "keyval" ).val();